# What Nuget packages must be referenced by an ASP.NET Core 6 application parts project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6 application in which I want to integrate additional areas provided by separate assemblies. I follow the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-6.0. In a project that provides app parts, I add an extension method for `IMvcBuilder` which allows me to register the parts assembly conveniently, for instance:

```cs
services.AddMvc().AddFeatureXyzParts();
```

The extension does nothing more like this:

```cs
public static IMvcBuilder AddFeatureXyzParts(this IMvcBuilder builder)
{
    if (builder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
    builder.AddApplicationPart(typeof(MvcBuilderExtensions).Assembly);
    return builder;
}
```

In the project file, I changed the `Sdk` attribute from `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` to reference the ASP.NET Core 6 SDK implicitly (as it is set up for the main application project), but this breaks the build with the error stating that the assembly lacks the definition of a `Main` method.

Since it is not a standalone web application assembly, but a parts library shipping additional controller types and services, I´d like to set the `Sdk` property back to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`. Then I have to add missing package references manually. For this, the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package seems to be the wrong choice for ASP.NET Core 6, and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Refs` must not be used.

What references do I need instead?

**Update** - Define the required entry point to satisfy the build

As a workaround that allows me to reference the required ASP.NET Core 6 SDK, I can use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK if I add an internal `Program` class that defines a `Main` method. With this in place, I can register my part assembly as wanted, and controllers (even if part of an area) integrate nicely.

```cs
internal static class Program
{
    public static void Main() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can just add `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>` to library projects `.csproj` file as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <!--... rest of file-->

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--... rest of file-->
</Project>
```

Comment: This is 100000x times easier than trying to find every single package reference.

Comment: never thought that it would be so easy. So can we use this in worker app too ?

Comment: @vibs2006 yes, for sure. Though it still will require corresponding runtime installed.

Comment: with Microsoft.AspNetCore.App takes almost 4 minutes to do a restore in CI/CD  (azure pipelines)

Comment: @JuanZamudio TBH have not experienced the same.