# Getting warnings when having netstandard2.0 ASP.net Core nuget packages referenced

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2022

I have a lib project which uses .net standard 2.0

I'm getting 5 warnings, that say could not load type:
`FixerWithFixAllAnalyzer`, `DiagnosticAnalyzerFieldsAnalyzer`, `DiagnosticDescriptorCreationAnalyzer`, `CSharpRegisterActionAnalyzer`, `ReportDiagnosticAnalyzer`

examples:

```
Warning CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.MetaAnalyzers.CSharpReportDiagnosticAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll: Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.MetaAnalyzers.ReportDiagnosticAnalyzer`4' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, Version=3.3.3.10305, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'..   MyLib (netstandard2.0)  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll  1   Active  System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.MetaAnalyzers.ReportDiagnosticAnalyzer`4' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, Version=3.3.3.10305, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerFileReference.Extensions`1.GetAnalyzersForTypeNames(Assembly analyzerAssembly, IEnumerable`1 analyzerTypeNames, Boolean& reportedError)

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Detail Description
Warning CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.MetaAnalyzers.CSharpRegisterActionAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll: Method 'GetCodeBlockAnalyzer' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.MetaAnalyzers.CSharpRegisterActionAnalyzer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation..   MyLib (netstandard2.0)  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll  1   Active  System.TypeLoadException: Method 'GetCodeBlockAnalyzer' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.MetaAnalyzers.CSharpRegisterActionAnalyzer' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerFileReference.Extensions`1.GetAnalyzersForTypeNames(Assembly analyzerAssembly, IEnumerable`1 analyzerTypeNames, Boolean& reportedError)
```

using `VS2022 17.4.4`

tried deleting all `bin/obj` folders, rebooting after

UPDATE:
To isolate I've deleted all the files in the project.
In my project file I have this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />    
 </ItemGroup>
```

when I remove it the warnings disappear, but when they are present I can also see some MVC warnings under .netstandard2.0, I'm attaching screenshot: [image]

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using `VS2022 17.4.4`, which I believe is the latest

Comment: Have you tried the "usual" - delete bin and obj folders, reboot the VS, reboot the machine?

Comment: @GuruStron I just tried all that you just said, after Rebuild I'm getting all the warnings back

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't help without a [mre]. Check the projects for some "suspicious" packages but that's mostly it in terms of what I can suggest.

Comment: Have you considered moving from `.netstandard`? Also try removing the ASP.NET Core packages and adding `FrameworkReference` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71321740/2501279)

Comment: @GuruStrong it is a library that is targeting both `netstandard2.0` and `netcoreapp3.1`;
regarding your solution I'm getting: `The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' was not recognized`

Comment: try conditional reference for multitarget project. Also why are you referencing only those two if you are upgrading to .NET 7?

Comment: @GuruStron that's what I'm doing, I do conditional referencing, I'm using `FrameworkReference Include` for 3.1, for 2.0 standard I reference nuget packages, I noticed the problem after updating the project (demo) that uses the library to 7, I guess that's irrelevant now, after isolating the problem

Answer (score 0):

Without additional context I could not answer about this issues:

> I'm getting 5 warnings, that say could not load type:
> FixerWithFixAllAnalyzer, DiagnosticAnalyzerFieldsAnalyzer,
> DiagnosticDescriptorCreationAnalyzer, CSharpRegisterActionAnalyzer,
> ReportDiagnosticAnalyzer

But I can answer the second part.

The analyzers that are shown under Project->Dependencies in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer (your screen-shot) only explain which issues they analyze. In other words, those are not actual errors in your project, but issues that are being checked for. As a concrete example lets take Microsoft.EnittyFrameworkCore.Analyzer, which have only analyzes one issue `EF1001: Internal EF Core API usage.` You can see in the official [git repository](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Analyzers/AnalyzerReleases.Shipped.md) where that error code is defined.

So each included analyzer checks for certain defined number of issues which are shown in the Visual Studio's Error List window (usually after build or after Project -> Analyze and Code Cleanup -> Run Code Analysis

Comment: the issues shown in the image are there without having any code in the project,  I've deleted all files; simply by having .net standard 2.0 ASP.net Core packages gives these errors

Comment: @buga Maybe you did not understand me. Those issues (from the image) are not issues at all. Those only indicate what issues are to be capture and analysed. Only issues you should worry about are in the "Error list"

Comment: I think they might be related to the warnings I'm getting,

Comment: @buga Can you add a screenshot of the warnings and stack trace (if there is some)?

Comment: I've updated the question, see after `examples:`

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the NuGet cache?

Comment: yes I tried all that

Comment: Hmmm.. Why it is trying to read the NuGet package from "NuGetFallbackFolder"? Have you done NuGet restore after the cache deletion? Do not know what else it could be