# How to register Infrastructure layer dependencies in Clean Architecture using .NET 6?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, clean-architecture

I am implementing a project using Clean Architecture in .NET 6. As per the Clean Architecture principle we should not reference Infrastructure layer in Web Api(Presentation layer), we should only access Application layer in Web Api.

So how can I register Infrastructure layer's dependencies without violating the Clean Architecture principle? I have created below extension method in Infrastructure layer to register dependencies:

```
namespace JwtWithIdentityDemo.Infrastructure.IoC
{
    public static class RegisterInfrastructure
    {
        public static void AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.Configure<JwtSetings>(configuration.GetSection(JwtSetings.SectionName));
            services.AddSingleton<IJwtTokenGenerator, JwtTokenGenerator>();
            services.AddTransient<IUserManagerWrapper, UserManagerWrapper>();

            // For Identity
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddScoped<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();

            // For Entity Framework
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("JwtWithIdentityDemoDb"),
          sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)
              .EnableRetryOnFailure(
                  maxRetryCount: 5,
                  maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                  errorNumbersToAdd: null)
            ),
                ServiceLifetime.Transient
            );

        }

    }
}
```

If I call `AddInfrastructure` method in Program.cs then I have to add reference of Infrastructure library, which is violating the Clean Architecture's principles.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
    builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<Program>());

    builder.Services.AddApplication(builder.Configuration);
    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration)

}
```

Comment: _"which is violating the Clean Architecture's principles."_ - which one exactly?

Comment: @GuruStron If I call method  builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration) from Program.cs(Web Api), then I have to add reference of Infrastructure layer into Web Api, but In Clean Architecture, the infrastructure layer should not be accessed directly from the presentation layer, which includes the web API. Instead, the presentation layer should access the application layer, which in turn can access the infrastructure layer.

Comment: Can you please show a link claiming that? The main rule is "Nothing in an inner circle can know anything at all about something in an outer circle.". If you want to go purist you can split the app in two - create a separate library for ASP.NET Core level (controllers, views, js, etc.) and then create another project will be a composition root and will link everything. But usually it is an overkill.

Comment: _"the application layer, which in turn can access the infrastructure layer"_ - this actually breaks the main rule of Clean architecture (if you mean that application layer references the infrastructure one).

Comment: @GuruStron, No, I mean, Application layer may have abstractions, and implementation will be in Infrastructure. for example, In my project I have IJwtTokenGenerator interface which is in Application layer, but implementation in Infrastructure layer. Because I am using IJwtTokenGenerator directly in controller, so I that's why I have created interface in the Application layer.

Comment: Again - if you want to go purist - create a separate project for composition root and move infrastructure and ASP.NET Core stuff in different ones and add all of them to the root one.

Comment: @GuruStron, Do you mean If I add reference of Infrastructure layer in Web Api, it is not violating the clean architecture? Actually I am new to Clean Architecture, I was going through some articles online, and somewhere i read like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that using `AddInfrastructure` in the web application project (hence adding link to Infrastructure from it) is not violating the main principle (in my opinion) of the [the clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html):

> Nothing in an inner circle can know anything at all about something in an outer circle. In particular, the name of something declared in an outer circle must not be mentioned by the code in the an inner circle.

Web API and `Infrastructure` are concepts of the same level and `Program` is your composition root.

If you really want to go purist you can extract actual application-relevant ASP.NET Core code into a separate library and have a separate project for composition root:

- MyProject.WebService
  references all components including `MyProject.Web` and `MyProject.Infrastructure` and contains `Program`
- MyProject.Web
  Class library with [`<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71321740/2501279), containing controllers and stuff
- MyProject.Infrastructure

It will introduce a bit more ceremony but not much.

Also check out [this](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture) and [this](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture) github repos.

Comment: Can I add MyProject.Common library for common utilities(i.e. enums, extension methods etc.) in Clean Architecture and use that in all other layers?

Comment: @RakeshKumar dependent on actual enum it potentially should part of entities layer. As for miscellaneous utils - yes, it makes sense to share it between all projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding according to the following sources it should be OK to reference Infrastructure layer in Web Api (Presentation layer) to be able to register the dependencies:

[Why is Clean Architecture so Popular?](https://codeopinion.com/why-is-clean-architecture-so-popular/)

[image: Why is Clean Architecture so Popular?]

[Decide which architecture to use - Clean architecture topic](https://www.mariusburghelea.tech/p/decide-which-architecture)
[image: Decide which architecture to use - Clean architecture topic]