# Issue referencing the connection string stored in Main app in repository Layer net 7.0

Tags: c#

I have created a repository layer "DB first" generated from the DB. So by default it places the connection string in the `OnConfiguring` method.

In .net Core 1.1 (last time I did this). I created a config.json file to store this value alongside the appsettings.json file. Then in the Startup.cs file I had:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
               
        // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
        builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
    }
    _configuration = builder.Build();
    _env = env;
}
```

Then followed this with the ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton(_configuration);
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(_configuration);
    ....
```

Then all the way down my layers to my repository layer I could do:

```
public partial class mydbContext
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public mydbContext(IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
         _config = config;
    }
    
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@_config["ConnectionStrings:mydbContextConnection"]);
}
```

This was very clean as it kept seperation of concern between my layers. The only reference to my repository layer was through my service layer.

Now using the Latest version .Net 7. I no longer have a startup.cs file only a program.cs file.

Looking round the internet and at the Microsoft documentation. The suggestion is that in program.cs

I should do `builer.Services.AddDbContext<mydbContext>......`

However, this really stinks as it means that I now have to reference my repository layer directly in the main app. Is there a better way of doing this in .Net 7.0.

to keep it simple I have

1. Main Project
2. service Layer
3. Repository Layer.

in my net core 1.1 app The only way the main project could get to the repository layer was via the service layer. I'm trying to keep it that way in my .net 7.0 solution too.

Comment: _"However, this really stinks as it means that I now have to reference my repository layer directly in the main app"_ - not sure what the problem here is. The "Main app" is composition root and it is natural for it to have reference for everything. Also I would argue that DI approach with `DbContextOptions` is more decoupled than injecting `IConfiguration` and calling `UseSqlServer` in the context itself.

Comment: Yes, exactly...I want the repository layer decoupled from the front end app. The issue is that should a hacker hit the site, tthey now have a direct reference to the DB. My way means they would not and would need to navigate my service layer too, making it more difficult to get access to the DB.

Comment: TBH I don't see any difference whatsoever. They would have it either way. Can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: My way there is no project reference in the main app to the repository app. The Microsoft way there is.

Comment: And how the main app interacts with the db? Even if the "repository app" is a transitional dependency or is loaded dynamically it does not make your app more secure. The dll is still on the server and connection string is still in the config.

Comment: If attacker is able to execute arbitrary code somehow in your only existence of the connection string available via config is enough to compromise the site.

Comment: It's about seperation of concern, loose coupling etc. now it's making it tightly coupled. Think about the 'onion schematic' each layer is seperate from each other, the top layer has a reference to the next layer, the next layer has a reference to the next and so on, now each layer isn't binding that way

Comment: Again, your original code is more tightly coupled from my point of view. If you want to go purist you can move app specific ASP code to a separate project and then reference everything in your separate composition root ASP app. But in my experience it is not worth the hustle.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865452/2501279)