# Blazor Server Get RemoteIpAddress after .NET 8 Upgrade

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, upgrade, httpcontext, .net-8.0

We were using the following solution to get the remote IP address of the client computer when running Blazor server.

We inject IHttpContextAccessor into the _Host.cshtml file and store the RemoteIpAddress.

```
 @inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
 @{
     var remoteIpAddress = 
    httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
  }

 ...
 <component type="typeof(App)" param-RemoteIpAddress=remoteIpAddress 
 render-mode="Server" />
```

You can read the full details here.  [How do I get client IP and browser info in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982444/how-do-i-get-client-ip-and-browser-info-in-blazor/75908259#75908259)

I'm now upgrading the code the .NET 8 and am in the process of replacing the _Host.cshtml with the App.razor.  So I'm wondering if there is any change to this solution now that I'm using .NET 8 and have no _Host.cshtml.  Maybe I'm overthinking things here, but unfortunately for me to test it I need to deploy it and I don't have a fee environment to test this in right now.

Comment: It shouldn't change. `IHttpContextAccessor` is still available.

Comment: Use of IHttpContextAccessor is now highly discouraged. Use the new HttpContext cascading parameter instead. It’s available in the root component. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77353050/httpcontext-in-net-8-0