# Error CS1705 is complaining about package with higher version that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I suddenly started getting this error:

> Error CS1705 : Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

So, MSBuild seems to be complaining about `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=7.0.0.0` but that package doesn't even have a version 7.0.0.0 (latest version available on nuget.org is 2.2.0).

Background is I'm building a library suite that supports most platforms and is also supposed to be backward compatible with .NET standard 2.0, so most of my nugets can target multiple .Net versions (netstandard2.0 --> net7).

Problems with these kinds of errors is MSBuild doesn't provide any hints as to *where* the problem exists, such as which package is causing it. Are there any tools available these days to help untangle these types of dll-hell situations? I've spent many hours trying to decrypt this error but so far no luck.

Comment: The problem is: `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.2.0.0`. Check your project file.

Comment: My application project, that references the library (nuget) projects does not refer to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`, nor `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features`, directly or indirectly. That is the problem; I assume those are referenced from a framework but I don't know how, or from what library.  It would be great if some tool could help clarify this

Comment: What is shown, when you choose 'Project', 'Manage Nuget packages'? Are they not shown there?

Comment: No, none of the mentioned libs are included so they must have been included indirectly, probably through the targeted framework.

Comment: I suggest you try installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=7.0.0.0,` and see what happens.

Comment: That package has been deprecated and there is no 7.0.0 version. This is one reason I find the error confusing. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I'm afraid that we don't have such a tool to help figure out which dlls causing the version conflict... could you please try to remind what did you do before this issue occurred? Just like what you said, latest version available on nuget.org is 2.2.0 for this package, so it looks like not resulting from an existing package....

Answer (score 1):

Out of ideas for how to track this culprit down I created a dependency visualization tree (with Rider) and then went on to try and build every library (nuget) project from the 'root' (no dependencies to other projects) and outward until I eventually got the problem.

Once I found the troublesome project I found this in the .csproj file, added automatically by Rider:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\7.0.14\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I tried comment that out and simply added a normal package reference instead, to the other `PackageReference` items in their `ItemGroup`:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
```

That, apparently, provided MSBuild with the exact info it needed.

The dangers of using too powerful tools I guess...

Comment: I would argue that you should use conditional package reference and conditional framework reference (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71321740/2501279 ).

Comment: Yes, that is probably a good idea. Currently I'm just not sure which framework should be referenced for netstandard2.0/2.1, vs more modern net6+